# How can I get the className of my table in cakephp 3?

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

In my AcosTable.php I have

```
$this->hasMany('ChildAcos', [
    'alias' => 'ChildAcos',
    'className' => 'Acos',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
]);
```

I need table name(className property) in appController. In my appController I have

```
$associations = $this->{$this->modelClass}->associations();
foreach ($associations->type('HasMany') as $item) {
    $options['name'] = $item->name();             //ChildAcos
    $options['foreignKey'] = $item->foreignKey(); //parent_id
    //$options['className'] = $item->?();         //Acos
    $hasMany[] = $options;
}
```

How can I retrieve className?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to all the other association options, there seems to be no way to get hold of the value of `Association::$_className`, you may want to report this over at [**GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), I think it wouldn't hurt to make this accessible too (at least readable).

For now it seems that all you can do is figure it from the target tables full classname, something like:

```php
$fqn = get_class($item->target());
$parts = namespaceSplit($fqn);
$className = substr(end($parts), 0, -5);
```

Comment: Thank you @ndm. I try this. << $association = $this->{$this->modelClass}->association();
  $fqn = get_class($association->target());
  $parts = namespaceSplit($fqn);
  $className = substr(end($parts), 0, -5);
  pr($className); >> But I meet this error <<Missing argument 1 for Cake\ORM\Table::association() >>. Also I put the problem in github and they propose to do something like this << $association->target()->registryAlias(); >> That generates similar error :(

Comment: 1. How can I supply parameter for association() automatically? 2. get_class returns Cake\ORM\Table that don't contain class name

Comment: @anghazighermezi Please don't expect me to spoonfeed you, that's really just programming 101. The method expects an argument, you _must_ supply it, there's no away around if you intend to use it. Also the code you are showing here is different to the one in your question.

Comment: @anghazighermezi `registryAlias()` won't work as the target table is being registered with the alias specified in the association. And when `get_class()` returns `Cake\ORM\Table`, this means that you are referencing a table for which no actual class exists,  `TableRegistry::get()` will return a magically created one based on `\Cake\ORM\Table` (`get_class(TableRegistry::get('MajorBeeForPresident'))`) in that case.

Comment: Thank you @ndm. I apologize if I could not express my purpose clearly. I got it wrong ( association instead of associations :)